# JQuery mobile changing color to clicked list view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a list view where its data is being loaded from JSON string. Refer to the below code. It will show the item name and quantity.

```
function loadItemsForList2(){
    //load items in page for list 2
    //empty existing items from shoppinglist2
    $("#shoppingList2").empty();
    //regenerate listTwoItems
    var lstTwo = localStorage.getItem("listTwo");
    if (lstTwo!=null) listTwoItems = JSON.parse(lstTwo);

        for (var key in listTwoItems) {
            item2 = key; //+ ":" +  listTwoItems[key];
            item2Qty = listTwoItems[key];
        $('#shoppingList2').append('<li class="list"><a class="itemList2"><div><span class="itemInList">' + item2 + '</span><span class="itemInListQty">'+ item2Qty+'</span></div></a><a class="removalLst2"></a></li>');
        }
    //goto to the page
    $.mobile.changePage("#finalShoppingList2");
    $("#shoppingList2").listview('refresh');
```

}

I wish that when the user clicks on an item in a list (li> ), it changes the background color. And when it is re-clicked again, it will go to the original color. Below is the function being called when list item is clicked. Note that only the outside line background is being changed to yellow. I need to change whole

background to yellow.

What I'm doing wrong. Kindly refer to the image [List view showing yellow line background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUwh6.jpg)
Please how can I solve this problem

```
$("#shoppingList2").delegate(".itemList2", "click", function() {

        selectedItem = $(this).text();
        //alert(selectedItem);
        selectedItem = selectedItem.replace(/\d+/g, '');
        alert(selectedItem);
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "yellow");

});
```

Comment: what exactly issue you have? and add code in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the backcolor of the 2 anchor tags in the list item:

```
$("#shoppingList2").on("click", ".itemList2", function() {
    selectedItem = $(this).text();
    selectedItem = selectedItem.replace(/\d+/g, '');
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).next("a").css("background-color", "yellow");    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/bBQNBN)**

Comment: Thanks for your demo. Please, how can I add the background color to the 2 anchor tags when the list is loaded. I tried to add some css to ".itemList2" class but it is not working.  a.itemList2{background: yellow;}

Comment: just add a !important:  a.itemList2{background: yellow !important;}

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the background color of parent of `.itemList2` which is `li`. But that `li` contains anchor tag and a div tag inside it. So Change the background color of that `div tag`.

Comment: That way only the color surrounded to the words will be colored and not complete <li></li>